# Create a function that creates x rows and y columns of "*"

Tags: javascript, html

The output (in this case) I want is three rows of "**" as the row is 3 and the column is 2.

```
  function drawbox(row,column){
    for (var j=0;j<row;j++)
    {
    for (var i=0;i<column;i++)
    {   document.write("*");
        if (i=(column-1))
          {document.write("<br>")}

    }

    }              
  }

  drawbox(3,2);


</script>
```

Comment: Stick the document.write("<br>") outside of the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple - just use two loops but don't worry about the `if`:

```js
function drawBox(row, column) {
  for (let i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < column; j++) {
      document.write("*");
    }
    document.write("<br>");
  }
}

drawBox(3, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is much simpler. Could you tell me why my function doesn't work? What's the logical flaw here? Thx!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative answer with ES6 and functional programming (because I love FP that much):

```
function drawbox(rows, columns){
    const row = Array(columns).fill().map(() => '*').join('');
    const _rows = Array(rows).fill().map(() => row).join('<br/>');
    document.write(_rows);   
}
```

Comment: const drawbox = (r, c) => document.write(Array(r).fill().map(() => Array(c).fill().map(() => '*').join('')).join('<br/>'))

Answer (score 2):

We can use [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) function

```
 <script> 


  function drawbox(row,column){
    for (var j=0;j<row;j++)
    {

     document.write("*".repeat(column));

     document.write("<br>")

    }              
  }

  drawbox(3,2);


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, I think:

```
function grid(row, col){
    document.write(Array(row).fill(Array(col).fill('*')).join('<br>'));
}
```

Also note: you're function isn't working because you're using the assignment operator:

```
if (i=(column-1))
```

...when you should be using the equality comparison operator:

```
if (i===(column-1))
```

Comment: Yeah! that's the one addressing my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Something I learned in my early days. When you deal with 2-dimensional data structures, The second dimension in a structural sense is oftentimes redundant.

Displaying data in 2 dimensions requires also just 1 loop only, not 2 and not 4 as shown in the other solutions.

```
const drawbox = (r, c) => {
  for (let ri = 1, i = 0;  i < r*c; ri++, i++) {
    document.write('*')
    if (ri >= r && i !== r*c) {
      document.write('<br>')
      ri = 0
    }
  }
}
```

You could use `i` only (without `ri`) in the for loop with the module operator -> `if (i%r === 0)` to figure out if a line break should be inserted.

```
const drawbox = (r, c) => {
  for (let i = 1;  i < r*c+1; i ++) {
    document.write('*')
    if (i%r === 0 && i !== r*c) {
      document.write('<br>')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This requires more logic and creativity tho, thanks!